# How to create a bar plot and show average Y values

Tags: r, bar-chart

I want to create a bar plot based on the following data:

```
Station    Delay
A          5
B          6
A          4
A          3
B          8
```

X axis should contain stations "A" and "B", while bars (Y axis) should show average delay per a station.

I tried this, but it does not give a correct result:

```
barplot(c(data$Station, data$Delay), 
        main="BARPLOT", xlab="Stations", ylab="Delays", 
        names.arg=data$Station)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(Station = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B"),    Delay= c(5, 6, 4, 3, 8))

library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(Station) %>% summarise(me = mean(Delay))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x = Station, y = me), data = df) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

or directly with `stat_summary`

```
ggplot(aes(x = Station, y = Delay), data = df) + stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar")
```

Comment: if you're going the `ggplot` route, you can do `ggplot(data, aes(Station, Delay)) + stat_summary(geom='bar', fun.y='mean')`

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can do:

```
m_data <- data.frame(data$Station, m_del=ave(data$Delay, data$Station), stringsAsFactors=F)
barplot(unique(m_data)$m_del, names=unique(m_data)$Station, main="BARPLOT", xlab="Stations", ylab="Delays")
```

Or with the package `data.table`, you can do:

```
library(data.table)
m_data <- setDT(data)[, mean(Delay), by=Station]
m_data[, barplot(V1, names=Station, main="BARPLOT", xlab="Stations", ylab="Delays")]
```

[image]